# How can I stop AutoCAD from zooming to model extents when changing a model's viewing angle by clicking on the WCS view cube?

Tags: autocad, 3d-modelling

Is there a parameter (and what is it?) that I can change in AutoCAD 2023 to stop it from auto zooming to a 3d model's extents when changing a model's viewing angle by clicking on the WCS view cube?

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Options** > **3D Modelling** > **ViewCube** and untick this option:

[image]